# Using a switch/case for array index

Tags: arrays, swift, count, switch-statement

I am trying to get the count of the indexes in an array and build cases of of the count but I am not able to build it properly nor an I find anything online or in the docs about it. So far I have the following...

```
 for array.count in theArray {
     switch array.count {
     case 1...5 :
       //do something
     case 6...10 :
       //do something
     case > 10 :
       //do something
     default :
       //do something
     } //close for switch        
 }//close for for/in
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of array.count use only array as it is a Element of Array theArray

```
let theArray = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,3,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,3,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,3,5,6]]

for array in theArray {
    switch array.count {
    case 1...5 : print("Under 5")
    case 6...10 :  print("Between 6 to 10")
    case let count where count > 10 /*or 10..<Int.max*/ : print("More than 10")
    default : break
    }
}
```

Comment: I see so you don't need to declare the count in the Element. Let me ask one follow on, if I wanted to build a case where I am saying, "Case if array.count is greater than 10". How would that look?

Comment: `10..<.max` or `case let count where count > 10`

Comment: Added the case for more than 10. Please mark it as an accepted answer if your problem is solved by this.

Comment: by doing this way I believe my results are printing out  after each iteration of the array in... "for array in theArray" How can I make this so I get the whole count and then base the case off of the total count for the array once it is called?

Comment: I have and I am working with a different type of array. I want to basically say here is an array with 3 elements in it. CASE: If the array has 1 through 3 elements print "There are 1 to 3 elements int the array". CASE: If the array has 5 to 10 elements  print "There are 1 to 3 elements int the array" CASE If the array has more than 10 print "TOO MUCH"